# How to compute percentages in BigQuery SQL for SUM?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to compute the Percentage of a specific column in a table, here's an example

```
Food              Quantity
Lemon                2
Mango                8
SweetJuice           10
Water                20
```

I want to obtain a table like this:

```
Food              Quantity_pc
Lemon                5
Mango                20
SweetJuice           25
Water                50
```

Note that this result is not grouped and I have just added this example to simplify the problem.
Here's what am trying to do:

```
Select Food, (Quantity/Sum(Quantity))*100 as Quantity_pc
From `FoodTable`;
```

But it's throwing me this error:

> bigquery error: 400 SELECT list expression references column Decision
>   which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want window functions:

```
select food, quantity * 100 / sum(quantity) over () as quantity_percent
from `foodtable`;
```

Comment: Wow, this is so useful, thanks so much. Just a quick doubt, after obtaining this result will it be possible to group by food? :sweat_smile:

Comment: Also, How do we round this number?

Comment: @ShivamSahil . . . You would use the `round()` function.

Comment: Yeah, just tried using it like this: round(quantity * 100 / sum(quantity) over (),0) still it appears in the same decimal format